# A Cosine Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

What is the value of the Cosine integral
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos\left( \frac{x (x^{2}-a^{2})}{x^{2}-b^{2}} \right) \, \frac{dx}{x^{2} + p^{2}} \, \, \, ?
\end{align}

Comment: Assume the intended meaning of 'value' is 'closed form expression', what makes you believe it might have one?

Comment: @Sasha the number of poles that can be obtained would suggest it has a closed form solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\pi}{2p} \exp\left[-p\frac{a^2+p^2}{b^2+p^2}\right]$$

This was submitted as a problem to the Gazette of the Royal Math. Soc. of Spain and is still open, so the solution will not be given here. Methods for the general class of integrals of this sort will be found in the book (in preparation)
``Fun With Integrals" (Borwein and Glasser)

Comment: An attempt was made to generalize the proposed problem in La Gaceta without losing the intent.